# How do I internationalize instance variables in button_to methods in my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a number of view files that I am trying to internationalize. One of these files happens to have lines of code such as this one:

```
= button_to t('.spam'), label_as_spammer_account_path(@topic.account), method: :post,
  data: { confirm: t('.spam_confirmation'), user: @topic.posts.first.account.name }, class: 'btn btn-mini btn-warning'
```

The part that I am trying to I18n is particularly the data confirm part of the message. How do I internationalize the `@topic.posts.first.account.name` part of the message? So far I have this in my topics.en.yml file (condensed of course)

```
topics:
  show:
    spam_confirmation: "Are you sure you want to mark %{user} as a spammer, disabling the account and removing all posts?"
```

The `%{user}` part refuses to be internationalized no matter how I modify the code above.

I've tried:

```
data: { confirm: t('.spam_confirmation'), user: "@topic.posts.first.account.name" }
data: { confirm: t('.spam_confirmation'), user: #{@topic.posts.first.account.name} }
data: { confirm: t('.spam_confirmation'), user: "#{@topic.posts.first.account.name}" }
```

At this point, I'm just trying to do whatever to see if anything works. I have to be specific though because rubocop/haml-lint complains if I don't do it just right. Help would be appreciated if anyone knows anything else I can try. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `user:` option to the `t` helper method:

```
data: { confirm: t('.spam_confirmation', user: @topic.posts.first.account.name) }
```